# How to have different mouse cursor on MOUSE_DOWN in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to as3 and I need to do a very simple thing. I have following code and it works pretty well. But what I need and can't figure out how to do it is:

1. change mouse cursor when I hold mouse button (choose from symbols)
2. ability to move with it (normally it would disappear when I move with mouse)

   ```
       import flash.display.Sprite;
       import flash.events.Event;
       import flash.events.MouseEvent;
       import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

       var CursorStill: Sprite;
       var CursorAnim: Sprite;

       function init() {
         Mouse.hide();

         CursorStill = new CursorStillClass();
         CursorStill.mouseEnabled = false;
         CursorStill.visible = false;

         addChild(CursorStill);

         stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
         stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
         stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
       }  

       function mouseMoveHandler(evt: MouseEvent): void {
         CursorStill.visible = true;
         CursorStill.x = evt.stageX;
         CursorStill.y = evt.stageY;
         evt.updateAfterEvent();
       }

       function mouseLeaveHandler(evt: Event): void {
         CursorStill.visible = false;

       }

       function mouseDownHandler (evt: MouseEvent): void {
         CursorStill.visible = false;
       }

       init();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

a friend of mine helped me and i figured it out. i hope it will help other newbies at least :)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

function init() {
    Mouse.hide();

    // this creates an instance of the library MovieClip with the
    // name, "MyCursorClass".  this contains your mouse cursor art
    //
    Cursor = new CursorClass();
    Cursor.mouseEnabled = false;
    Cursor.visible = false;

    // you'll want to make sure the child is added above everything
    // else, possibly in its own container
    //
    addChild(Cursor);

    // respond to mouse move events
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    // whenever the mouse moves, place the cursor in the same spot
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Cursor.x = evt.stageX;
    Cursor.y = evt.stageY;
    // for smoother mouse pointer
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseLeaveHandler(evt: Event): void {
    Cursor.visible = false;

}

function mouseDownHandler(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    Cursor.gotoAndStop(xx);
}

function mouseUpHandler(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    Cursor.gotoAndStop(xx);
}

init();
```

most credits goes to this tutorial though

http://danielmclaren.com/2008/03/tips-for-using-custom-mouse-cursors-in-flash-as3